# How to use Mandrill to send email report in Scrapy Spidermon

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, mandrill, spidermon

Currently, Scrapy Spidermon extension only shows an example to send email using Amazon Simple Email Service. Is it possible to use Mandrill instead? And how?

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as "accepted" if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own "Mandril Send Email" class.

Use [`SendSESEmail`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon/blob/master/spidermon/contrib/actions/email/ses.py) as a start point, but instead of handling AWS keys, you use your credentials for Mandrill.

You `send_message` should look something like this:

```
def send_message(self, message):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587)
    s.login(MANDRILL_USERNAME, MANDRILL_PASSWORD)
    s.send_message(message)
```

(based on this snippet: https://mandrill.com/#script-python)

Hope it helps you.